# How do you explicitly instantiate a member function template?

Tags: c++, function-templates, explicit-instantiation, c++-templates

In `Class.h`:

```
class Class {
public:
    template <typename T> void function(T value);
};
```

In `Class.cpp`:

```
template<typename T> void Class::function(T value) {
    // do sth
}
```

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Class.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Class a;
    a.function(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a linker error because `Class.cpp` never instantiates `void Class::function<int>(T)`.
You can explicitly instantiate a class template with :

```
template class std::vector<int>;
```

How do you explicitly instantiate a member template of a non-template class ?

Comment: I was asking the question in the context this blog post concerning boost's serialization library : http://www.timoch.com/blog/2013/04/boost-serialization-coupling-issue/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the following syntax in `Class.cpp`:

```
template void Class::function(int);
```

The template argument can be omitted because of type deduction, which works for function templates. Thus, the above is equivalent to the following, just more concise:

```
template void Class::function<int>(int);
```

Notice, that it is not necessary to specify the names of the function parameters - they are not part of a function's (or function template's) signature.

Comment: what if Class is also templated?

Comment: I might have figured it out:   template void B<char>::do_something<int>();
  https://godbolt.org/g/IhMwqM

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried with the following in `Class.cpp`?

```
template void Class::function<int>(int value);
```