# Instantiate a template member function

Tags: c++, templates

I have template member functions, but I cannot figure out how I can instantiate them when I am using them properly. The structure is as follows:

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
template<typename T>
T Func(T);
}
#include "foo.tpp"
```

```
// foo.tpp
template<typename T>
T Func(T input) {return(input);}
```

How should I instantiate the template if I want to realize the following code in the main function?

```
//main.cpp
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
    Foo obj;
    int int_input, int_output;
    int_output = obj.Func(int_input);
    double double_input, double_output;
    double_output = obj.Func(double_input);
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked answers for similar questions such as [Instantiation of template member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974080/instantiation-of-template-member-function), but I do not want to instantiate all the member functions for all combinations every time I use them. Another option might be defining the class as a template class and instantiate different classes  using `template class Foo<int>;`. However, this forces me to define different classes for different type of member functions, which I do not prefer. Is there other solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: You need `Foo::` in front of `Func` in your tpp file. Otherwise, they refer to different functions.

Comment: `T Func(T input) {return(input);}` should be `T Foo::Func(T input) {return(input);}`  After that, your code should just work.

Comment: I kind of like the encapsulation that `*.tpp` gives you. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much! I made a stupid mistake. It works now. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
T Func(T input) {return(input);}
```

This declares a free-standing function template in the global scope that is unrelated to your `Foo` class. To implement the member function, you need to prefix the function definition's name with `Foo::`, as you would for any other member function implementation.

```
template<typename T>
T Foo::Func(T input){ return input; }
```

Also note that `return(value);` as opposed to `return value;` is a slight anti-pattern. While this doesn't usually matter, it can make a difference when using things like the `decltype(auto)` inferred return type and cause an accidental dangling reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer! I have never used `decltype(auto)`, so never had problem with `return()`yet. I will learn and check a little.

Comment: It's a pretty advanced feature and you'll probably never need to worry about it. I just mentioned it for completeness' sake.