# coverage for enable_if template class functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates, code-coverage, type-traits

I'm trying to generate **accurate code coverage** for my templated math classes. I'm default instantiating every method inside a template class with a trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666800/getting-useful-gcov-results-for-header-only-libraries?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
template class Vector2D<float>;
```

so that the coverage is not always 100% but shows me, where functions were never called. The problem is that if i go further and use **type traits** to enable member functions of templated classes only for certain types, the coverage for these is again always at 100%. Both **gcov and llvm-cov** show that these functions are not generated. *I'm guessing it's because these function are their own "templates" within my templated class?*

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2D {

...

template <class U = T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value, void>::type rotate(
T angle) {
    ...
    }
};
```

How can i (default) instantiate these functions such that the coverage report will show them in orange/red if they are never called?

Comment: Not sure to understand but... have you tried defining a `using` as `using foo_type = decltype(std::declval<Vector2D<float>>().rotate(0.0f))` or something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up explicitly instantiating the template member function (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974080/instantiation-of-template-member-function))

```
template void Vector2D<float>::rotate<float>(float);
```

The coverage report then shows the function as never called (orange/red) if i indeed do not call it explicitly in code.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as classes, functions/methods can be explicitly instantiated:

```
template
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<F>::value, void>::type
Vector2D<float>::rotate<float>(float);
```

With C++20 `requires`, with:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2D {

//...

    void rotate(T angle) requires(std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
        //...
    }
};
```

I expect that only explicit class instantiation would be needed.

Comment: not 100% what i need, but you got me on the right track. Thanks! i'll post my answer to the question for future reference

Comment: It seems you can resolve the `std::enable_if`, so your answer is similar to mine.