# How to instantiate template constructor in template class/struct in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, clang

I have a template struct with template constructor:

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct Vector2
{
    template<typename F1>
    Vector2(const Vector2<F1>& vector);
};
```

Implementation for it:

```cpp
template<typename F>
template<typename F1>
Vector2<F>::Vector2(const Vector2<F1>& vector)
: Vector2(vector.x, vector.y)
{}
```

It is possible to instantiate this constructor for types float and double in Vector2<float> and Vector2<double> types?
I've tried:

```cpp
template struct Vector2<float>::Vector2(const Vector2<float>& vector);
// Errors: "Expected unqualified-id" and "Expected ')'"
template struct Vector2<float>::Vector2<float>(const Vector2<float>& vector);
// Errors: same as in the previous one
template struct Vector2::Vector2(const Vector2<float>& vector);
// Error: "Use of class template 'Vector2' requires template arguments"
template Vector2<float>::Vector2(const Vector2<float>& vector);
// Error: "Explicit instantiation refers to member function 'Vector2<float>::Vector2' that is not an instantiation"
```

Comment: Why not implement it (define it) where it is declared?

Comment: You are using Clang and Clang is taking a strict reading of the standard which doesn't permit explicit instantiation of a constructor template: Generally the template arguments on the function template specialization must be given explicitly, but that is specifically forbidden for constructors. When not specifying the template arguments explicitly, then they must be deduced. The deduction is done from the type of the function template specialization, but constructors do not have a type. So, there is no way to do such an explicit instantiation.

Comment: Just use the normal approach using implicit instantiation: Define the templated entities in the header file. The only reason to use explicit instantiation is to save on compilation time or header/build dependencies. But both shouldn't be important for a simple class like a vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly instantiate a class template

```
template struct Vector2<float>;
```

If you want to explicitly instantiate a class member template (GCC and MSVC only)

```
template Vector2<float>::Vector2(const Vector2<float>& vector);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try instantiate member as you write I get error "Explicit instantiation refers to member function 'ASE::Vector2<float>::Vector2' that is not an instantiation"

Comment: Instantiating the class specialization won't solve OP's issue. GCC accepts the last syntax, while Clang does not. GCC is probably taking an overly lax interpretation of the standard. See my comment under the question.

Comment: @user17732522 Are you saying this is a wrong accepted answer [How do you explicitly a member function template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974080/how-do-you-explicitly-instantiate-a-member-function-template)?

Comment: @273K There is no problem with member function templates in general. There is only a problem with constructor templates. And Clang seems to accept the analogues explicit specialization declaration, so maybe I am interpreting its error message wrong. I am not entirely sure, but from the standard it is definitively not obvious to me how that explicit instantiation declaration should work.